# Edit Action don't work in Custom Module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, database, custom, edit

When I open the edit form in admin, the fields are empty, the data is not loaded from DB. Loading still work.

**Files:**

Form.php
https://pastebin.com/8TJ54KSi

StoreController.php
https://pastebin.com/utZ0ydHR

Edit.php
https://pastebin.com/WHTCQ03c

Grid.php
https://pastebin.com/MrxfYpTc

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below changes that I have made:

1.) Put below **edit function** in your **store controller**

```
public function editAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("store_id");
    $model = Mage::getModel("store/block")->load($id);
    if ($model->getStoreId()) {
        Mage::register("store_block", $model);
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock("store/adminhtml_store_edit"));
        $this->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock("store/adminhtml_store_edit_tabs"));
        $this->renderLayout();
    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError(Mage::helper("store")->__("Item does not exist."));
        $this->_redirect("*/*/");
    }
}
```

2.) add below code in Tabs.php within `Offline/Store/Block/Adminhtml/Store/Edit/`

```
<?php
class Offline_Store_Block_Adminhtml_Store_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId("store_tabs");
        $this->setDestElementId("edit_form");
        $this->setTitle(Mage::helper("store")->__("Item Information"));
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->addTab("form_section", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("store")->__("Item Information"),
        "title" => Mage::helper("store")->__("Item Information"),
        "content" => $this->getLayout()->createBlock("store/adminhtml_store_edit_tab_form")->toHtml(),
        ));
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

3.) add below code in Form.php within `Offline/Store/Block/Adminhtml/Store/Edit/`

```
<?php
class Offline_Store_Block_Adminhtml_Store_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            "id" => "edit_form",
            "action" => $this->getUrl("*/*/save", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("store_id"))),
            "method" => "post",
            "enctype" =>"multipart/form-data",
        ));
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

4.) add below code in Form.php within `Offline/Store/Block/Adminhtml/Store/Edit/tab/`

```
<?php
class Offline_Store_Block_Adminhtml_Store_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset("store_form", array("legend"=>Mage::helper("store")->__("Item information")));
        $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'hidden', array(
            'name'      => 'store_id',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'name',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Name'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Name'),
            'required'  => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('short_description', 'textarea', array(
            'name'      => 'short_description',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Short description'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Short description'),
            'style'     => 'height:16em',
            'required'  => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('description', 'textarea', array(
            'name'      => 'description',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Description'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Description'),
            'style'     => 'height:16em',
            'required'  => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('position', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'position',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Position'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Position'),
            'required'  => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Status'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Status'),
            'name'      => 'status',
            'required'  => true,
            'options'   => Mage::getModel('store/source_status')->toArray(),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('country', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'country',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Country'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Country'),
            'required'  => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('state_province', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'state_province',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('State/Province'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('State/Province'),
            'required'  => false,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('city', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'city',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('City'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('City'),
            'required'  => false,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('street', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'street',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Street'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Street'),
            'required'  => false,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('zip_code', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'zip_code',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Zip Code'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Zip Code'),
            'required'  => false,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('telephone', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'telephone',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Telephone'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('store')->__('Telephone'),
            'required'  => false,
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getStoreBlock()) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getStoreBlock());
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setStoreBlock(null);
        }  elseif(Mage::registry("store_block")) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry("store_block")->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```